# Regex for removing all characters except A-z and deleting all words containing digits

Tags: python, regex, replace

My goal is to write a function that inputs a text and substitutes all characters except for latin alphabet (A-z) with whitespaces, plus it deletes all the words containing digits. Then it replaces all multiple whitespace with a single one.

Example:

```
' hello, world! ho1hoho2ho, merry xmas!! ho1ho1 :))' -> 'hello world merry xmas'.
```

The Python function that implements this:

```
def clean_text(text):
    text_valid = re.sub(u'[^A-z0-9]', ' ', text)
    return ' '.join(word for word in text_valid.split()
                    if not re.search(r'\d', word))
```

Now I wonder if there is a single regular expression for this, maybe, so I could just write something like

```
return ' '.join(re.findall(enter_my_magical_regex_here))
```

Or, maybe, there is another way to replace the code above with something faster (and, hopefully, shorter)?

Comment: FYI: [`[A-z]` also matches some non-letter chars.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926)

Comment: That character set should be `[^0-9A-Za-z]` to match everything but ASCII digits and letters.  (`\W` would let underscores through.)

Comment: Do not use `[A-я]` to match Russian letters, you need to use `[А-Яа-яёЁ]`. English ones can be matched with `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: If you want to match only letters in the current locale, use a predefined character class for that, don't try to write one yourself.

Comment: Try `re.sub(ur'^\s*|\s*$|\s*(?:[^\W\d_]*\d[^\W\d_]*|[^A-Za-z\d\s]+)', '', text, flags=re.U)`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/40LlMp

Comment: ...so, for instance, `[[:alpha:]]` will understand the Russian alphabet when you're currently in a locale where that's in your character collation order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
' '.join(re.sub('([^A-Za-z0-9 ]|[^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*)', '', text).split())
```

Comment: What's the use of `u`?

Answer (score 1):

This will get you your desired output -

```
x = ' hello, world! ho1hoho2ho, merry xmas!! ho1ho1 :))'
re.sub('[!,]', '', ' '.join([i for i in x.split() if not re.findall('[\d+:\\?\"<>*/|]', i)]))
```

But you might have to tweak things here and there